# Unable to integrate Twitter Digit module using Fabric plugin in OSX 10

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am trying to integrate digits framework into my xcode project but its plugin keep saying that "Whoops, Something went wrong here!..."

I have these into my podfile

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Digits'
pod 'TwitterCore'
```

Screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HmixABGO51TkdteE83WHhvUW8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: At last I was able to get it through. Initially I tried to integrate Digits from a new project to make sure I am not missing anything. And it was successful. 

Then in my existing project I removed the complete setup using `pod clean` and did a [fresh pod setup][1] after cleaning the project to its base source, then it worked.


  [1]: https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: Yes, `pod clean` do exist on terminal. It removes all pod related stuff that you added with the project. I reintegrated, and updated all the pods to get it work again.